# Como colocar um botão em cima de uma imagem?

Tags: css

Tenho a seguinte imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso incluir um botão em cima dela usando CSS, tipo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código fonte:

```
<div id="exampleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <img src="https://progetex.com.br/uf/popup1.png" style="max-width:100%"/>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mas não posso usar a imagem de `background` da `div` porque preciso das dimensões dela (quando usei como background, a div não apareceu já que não tinha conteúdo dentro).

Alguma dica?

Comment: Sim. Use position: absolute no botão e bottom: TANTOSpx e left: TANTOSpx

Comment: Mas era bom colocar o código disso tudo pra gente dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: @dvd incluí o código, é um pedaço de um modal do boostrap. vou ver se consigo botar o botão usando position.

Comment: @dvd deu certo usando position. obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme discutido nos comentários, posicione o botão com `position: absolute;`:

```
botao{
   position: absolute;
   left: VALORpx;
   bottom: VALORpx
}
```

Substitua "VALOR" por números onde o botão fique na posição desejada. Troque também o seletor "botao" pelo `id`, `class` ou tag do elemento.